# Async Function in Javascript for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas

I'm fairly new to Javascript and I want to create a Video Player with a HTML Canvas element and then draw a Video into it with Javascript.

These are my functions for drawing it into the canvas:

```
async function startPlayback(vidSource){
   var video = document.getElementById('video');
   video.src = vidSource;
   video.loop = false;
   video.addEventListener('playing', paintVideo);
   video.play();
}
function paintVideo() {
   ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, can_div.width(), can_div.height());
   if (!video.paused) {
      requestAnimationFrame(paintVideo);
}
```

It works like this in Chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer. How can I make it work in IE?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: actually, just realised ... with the code you posted, simply remove `async` ... it's superfluous anyway as  it plays no part in the code at all - not sure why anyone would write such code in the first place, the mentality is *"ooh, look a new toy, lets use it"*

Comment: Also note that you are lucky your video element get the id `"video"`, because the variable you declared in `startPlayback` is inaccessible to `paintVideo`.